# After installing django in virtual environment, still can't import module

Tags: python, django, installation

I am trying to use django for web dev, but after I install it, I try to use import it in the interpreter and it says it gives me an import error. Here is what I do.

```
virtualenv venv --distribute
source venv/bin/activate
```

so now I am in the virtual environment (venv)

```
pip install django
python
import django
```

Then I get an ImportError

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Answer (score 2):

Original poster here.

I installed django using pip so it was in the python 2.7 binaries while i was working with python 3.5.

Using pip3 install django solved it.