# Installed django in virtual env, but I can't import

Tags: python, django

I installed Django in virtual env.

[image]

[image: Installed in venv]

But I got error.

```
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I use python 3.12.0 and tried reinstall all venv and packages, but got same error.

[After installing django in virtual environment, still can't import module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579042/after-installing-django-in-virtual-environment-still-cant-import-module) is not helpful.

Comment: Run `pip list` in your venv, is django on that list?

Comment: @agengha, I have 
`asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
djangorestframework==3.11.1
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1`
in my requirements

Comment: Django 3.1 isn’t compatible with Python 3.12; it will only run up to Python 3.9. It is also no longer supported and should NOT be used.

Comment: @FlipperPA, thanks. Then should I downgrade python?

Comment: I’d recommend going the other direction and upgrading Django. You can see this page for information on what versions of Django are supported: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions